# Cannot call front() on queue in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, tuples, future

I am attemtping to access and pop the front element from a queue in C++, but the line

```
tuple<int, string, future<string>> post = posterVerificationQueue.front();
```

is underlined in red and gives the error:

> function "std::tuple<_This, _Rest...>::tuple(const std::tuple<_This,
> _Rest...> &) [with _This=int, _Rest=<std::string, std::futurestd::string>]" (declared at line 320 of "C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\tuple") cannot
> be referenced -- it is a deleted function

I imagine it is an issue with me using a future within a tuple, but not too sure. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <queue>
#include <mutex>
#include <tuple>
#include <map>

#include "TCPClient.h"
#include "ThreadPool.h"
#include "RequestGenerator.h"
#include "ResponseVerifier.h"
#include "Storage.h"

#define DEFAULT_PORT 12345

void readRequest(string serverIp, int threadIndex, double timeDurationSecs);
void postRequest(string serverIp, int threadIndex, double timeDurationSecs);

int readRequests = 0;
int postRequests = 0;

mutex mLock;
map<int, tuple<double, int>> posterThreadMap;
queue<tuple<int, string, future<string>>> posterVerificationQueue;
map<int, tuple<double, int>> readerThreadMap;
Storage* db = new Storage();
RequestGenerator* requestGenerator = new RequestGenerator();

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // Default parameters
    unsigned int posterCount = 5;
    unsigned int readerCount = 0;
    double timeDurationSecs = 10;
    bool throttle = false;
    string serverIp = "127.0.0.1";

    // Validate the parameters
    if (argc != 6) {
        std::cout << "\nUsage (required parameters): server_IP number_of_poster_threads number_of_reader_threads time_duration throttle(0|1)\n\n";
        std::cout << "server_IP - IP of the server\n";
        std::cout << "number_of_poster_threads - number of threads performing POST operations\n";
        std::cout << "number_of_reader_threads - number of threads performing READ operations\n";
        std::cout << "time_duration - duration of test execution in seconds\n";
        std::cout << "throttle(0|1) - 0: do not throttle message speed\n";
        std::cout << "\t\t1: throttle message speed\n\n";

        std::cout << "\nDefault Parameters:\n";
        std::cout << "\tserver_IP - " << serverIp << "\n";
        std::cout << "\tnumber_of_poster_threads - " << posterCount << "\n";
        std::cout << "\tnumber_of_reader_threads - " << readerCount << "\n";
        std::cout << "\ttime_duration - " << timeDurationSecs << "s\n";
        std::cout << "\tthrottle - " << (throttle ? "true" : "false") << "\n\n";

        std::cout << "Enter dev mode using default paramaters?\n";
        system("pause");
    }
    else
    {
        serverIp = argv[1];
        posterCount = (int)argv[2];
        readerCount = (int)argv[3];
        timeDurationSecs = (int)argv[4];
        throttle = (int)argv[5];
    }

    cout << "\nStarting throughput test...\n";

    ThreadPool posterPool(posterCount);
    vector<future<void>> posterFutures;
    vector<tuple<string, int, int>> incorrectPostResponses;
    double posterTotalTime = 0.0; // The total time in seconds that all poster threads took to run


    ThreadPool readerPool(readerCount);
    vector<future<void>> readerFutures;
    double readerTotalTime = 0.0; // The total time in seconds that all reader threads took to run

    for (int i = 0; i < posterCount; i++)
        posterFutures.push_back(posterPool.enqueue(postRequest, serverIp, i, timeDurationSecs));

    for (int i = 0; i < readerCount; i++)
        readerFutures.push_back(readerPool.enqueue(readRequest, serverIp, i, timeDurationSecs));

    for (int i = 0; i < posterFutures.size(); i++)
        posterFutures[i].wait();

    for (int i = 0; i < readerFutures.size(); i++)
        readerFutures[i].wait();

    for (int i = 0; i < posterThreadMap.size(); i++)
    {
        double posterRequestsPerSecond = get<1>(posterThreadMap[i]);
        double threadRunTime = get<0>(posterThreadMap[i]);
        posterTotalTime += threadRunTime;
        std::cout << "\nPoster thread " << i << " (ran for " << threadRunTime << "s) - Average post requests per second: " << posterRequestsPerSecond << "\n";
    }

    // Should verification be optional?
    while (!posterVerificationQueue.empty())
    {
        tuple<int, string, future<string>> post = posterVerificationQueue.front();
        posterVerificationQueue.pop();

        int postIndex = get<0>(post);
        string request = get<1>(post);
        string response = get<2>(post).get();

        tuple<bool, int, int> postVerification = db->addPosterValue(postIndex, request, response);
        bool isValid = get<0>(postVerification);

        if (!isValid)
        {
            int correctResponse = get<1>(postVerification);
            int actualResponse = get<2>(postVerification);
            incorrectPostResponses.push_back(make_tuple(request, correctResponse, actualResponse));
        }
    }

    cout << "\nTotal poster runtime: " << posterTotalTime << "s" << "\n";
    cout << "\nTotal post requests: " << postRequests << "\n";
    cout << "\nAverage post requests per second per thread: " << postRequests / posterTotalTime << "\n";
    cout << "\nIncorrect responses: " << incorrectPostResponses.size() << "\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < incorrectPostResponses.size(); i++)
    {
        tuple<string, int, int> incorrectResponse = incorrectPostResponses[i];
        string request = get<0>(incorrectResponse);
        int correctResponse = get<1>(incorrectResponse);
        int actualResponse = get<2>(incorrectResponse);
        cout << "Incorrect response #" << i + 1 << "\n";
        cout << "Request: " << request << "\n";
        cout << "Expected response: " << correctResponse << "\n";
        cout << "Actual response: " << actualResponse << "\n\n";
    }

    // TODO: Implement the block above for reader threads

    delete db;
    delete requestGenerator;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

string sendRequest(TCPClient client, string request)
{
    return client.send(request);
}

void postRequest(string serverIp, int threadIndex, double timeDurationSecs)
{
    TCPClient client(serverIp, DEFAULT_PORT);
    client.OpenConnection();

    int threadPostCount = 0;
    double timeSpan;
    chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point endTime;
    chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point startTime = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    
    do
    {
        /*
            Could limit with
            if (!throttle || (throttle && threadPostCount < (timeDurationSecs * 1000)))
            {}
        */
        string request = requestGenerator->generateWriteRequest();
        mLock.lock();
        future<string> responseFut = async(launch::async, sendRequest, client, request);
        posterVerificationQueue.push(make_tuple(postRequests, request, move(responseFut)));
        postRequests++;
        mLock.unlock();
        threadPostCount++;

        endTime = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        timeSpan = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::duration<double>>(endTime - startTime).count();
    } while (timeSpan < timeDurationSecs);

    double totalRunTime = (endTime - startTime).count();
    double posterRequestsPerSecond = threadPostCount / timeSpan;

    tuple<double, double> returnValues = make_tuple(timeSpan, posterRequestsPerSecond);
    mLock.lock();
    postRequests += threadPostCount;
    posterThreadMap[threadIndex] = returnValues;
    mLock.unlock();

    client.CloseConnection();
}

void readRequest(string serverIp, int threadIndex, double timeDurationSecs)
{
    //return 0.0;
}
```

Comment: Please remove all unecessary code and add the necessary code to make it as close as possible to being compilable. See [mre]. [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/TPTE8rxKG)

Comment: imho, tuple<int, string, future<string>> post cannot be copied.

Comment: Try to change the initialization to `= std::move(posterVerificationQueue.front());`.

Comment: To clarify, your code is attempting to make two instances of the same `std::future`, which is not permitted.  The error is saying "copy construction has been deleted."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
std::tuple<_This, _Rest...>::tuple(const std::tuple<_This, _Rest...> &)
...
cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function
```

Well, that's the tuple copy constructor, right?

> I imagine it is an issue with me using a future within a tuple, but not too sure.

Let's check the documentation for [the constructors of `std::future`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/future) ...

> `future( const future& other ) = delete;`

> `std::future` is not *CopyConstructible*.

So I'd say your imagination was correct. You can't copy the tuple, because *it* can't copy one of its members.

You can use `std::move` to *move* construct from the queue element, but remember it would be a problem if you *didn't* `pop` the front immediately after (in the code shown, you do this, so it's fine).